# Error while updating ADT plugin for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

My eclipse showing an error message of **This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 20.0.0 or above. Current version is 16.0.0.v201203301601-306762. Please update ADT to the latest version."** after installing a newer revision of android sdk tools. So i update the ADT plugin in eclipse by **Help -> Check for updates** and install all the updates listed. But an error has occurred while installing. The error message is following

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=SDKProfile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Unknown Host:
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_22.3.0.v201310242005-887826.jar
>   dl-ssl.google.com Unknown Host:
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.base_22.3.0.v201310242005-887826.jar
>   dl-ssl.google.com Unknown Host:
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/features/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_22.3.0.v201310242005-887826.jar
>   dl-ssl.google.com Unknown Host:
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger_22.3.0.v201310242005-887826.jar
>   dl-ssl.google.com Unknown Host:
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/features/com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger_22.3.0.v201310242005-887826.jar
>   dl-ssl.google.com Unknown Host:
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/features/com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer_22.3.0.v201310242005-887826.jar
>   dl-ssl.google.com Unknown Host:
>   http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/features/com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview_22.3.0.v201310242005-887826.jar
>   dl-ssl.google.com

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: are you on windows ? if so try to restart eclipse and disable your antivirus for some time

Comment: please check your internet connection since its giving  Unknown Host:erro

Comment: no i am using linux. Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse 4.3 try to insert as avaible software site https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3

If it doesn't work try to insert as avaible software site https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The only related blog I found is [http://www.programmingrelief.com/2457785/Android--Unknown-Host-Errors-While-Installing-Adt-Plugin-In-Eclispe.](http://www.programmingrelief.com/2457785/Android--Unknown-Host-Errors-While-Installing-Adt-Plugin-In-Eclispe)

Let me know if this works.